# Texture Rendering Strangely

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials

When I render an image, the texture that is on my road plane changes. It doesn't show anywhere near as much detail as the texture 3D view suggests. I must have forgotten to check a box somewhere but I can't work out what I did wrong. Any ideas?

screenshots to show the difference:

[image: The way I want it to look when rendered]
As you can see I've put very low res stones in the dirt and a very basic grass texture, hopefully the picture size is enough to see it.

[image: The way it looks when rendered]
The stones are gone and the grass is missing its other shade.

There is also a strange green blend in the distance which isn't meant to be there, but I think that is probably another question.

Thank you :)

Comment: It is probably a mapping problem,Check if you are using the same UVs or projection type in the texture panel.

Comment: Do you have a subdivision surface modifier on the ground parts ? If yes its parameters can be different in view and render... just an idea to be checked.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the problem. I had forgotten to uncheck the 25 repeats.

I changed the base plane to be smaller and then use an array, but left it repeating the texture 25 times. Thank you for the answers :)

Also fixed the green in the background problem by selecting field in the texture panel.

Thank you for the suggestions Omar Ahmad and lemon.